# Automounting External USB 3.0 HDD with truecrypt on linux

Tags: linux, mount, truecrypt

Is it possible to mount my external HDD usb device which is encrypted with truecrypt on plug in?

I use it only on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to add an exception that allows to run truecrypt without password. So add this line to /etc/sudoers using the command "sudo visudo":

Code:
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/truecryptreplacing "username" with... well your username.

then you can place the truecrypt mount command in your autostart options

This answer found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1656645

Comment: :Is this going to automount the device when I plug in?Also ,note that I want to be prompted for password.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the command truecrypt -h gives Linux commandline support.

I always had TrueCrypt running at startup. Then plug in the USB in question and add to Truecrypt favorites and ask for password upon plug-in.

Selected or all favorite volumes can be mounted automatically whenever its host device gets connected to the computer. To set this up, follow these steps:

1.Mount the volume (to the drive letter to which you want it to be mounted every time). 
2.Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TrueCrypt window and select 'Add to Favorites'. 
3.The Favorites Organizer window should appear now. In this window, enable the option 'Mount selected volume when its host device gets connected' and click OK.

Then, when you insert e.g. a USB flash drive on which a TrueCrypt volume is located into the USB port, you will be asked for the volume password (and/or keyfiles) (unless it is cached) and if it is correct, the volume will be mounted.

Dave

Comment: :When I add to favorites it doesn't appear any option 'Mount selected volume when its host device gets connected'.Just 'Move up' etc

Answer (score 0):

George,

By your answer, it seems the TrueCrypt Linux version GUI doesn't match the Windows version.
I direct you here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/automount-truecrypt-truecrypt-command-lline-os-arch-linux-826365/
I feel that page has your answer.

Dave

Comment: :Executing this command , it gives me that it is already mounted!